# case when for both columns true not showing data

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two columns IsHomeDelivery and Ispurchase whose values can be 0 and 1.

When value is 1 then i have to show text.

Means when ishomedelevery=1 then 'homedelivery
ispurchase=1 then 'purchase'

i have formed following query:

```
SELECT
        LocationName,
        BranchName,
        AddLine1,
        AddLine2,
        Tel1,
        CASE
            WHEN LocationType='CC' THEN 'Call Center'
            WHEN LocationType='CL' THEN 'Operation'
        END AS 'Location Type',
        CASE
            WHEN IsPurchase= 1 THEN 'Purchase'
            WHEN IsHomeDelivery = 1 THEN 'Home Delivery'
            WHEN IsPurchase=1 AND IsHomeDelivery=1 THEN 'Purchase And Home Delevery'
        END AS 'Type'
    FROM PescaLocation
```

but unfortunatly its not working for both columns true.

Means when isHomedelivery and isPurchase both are 1 then it is showing 'purchase' whereas it should show 'home delivery and purchase'

plz help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a condition in your second case. "When IsPurchase = 1" will be true when both IsPurchase and IsHomeDelivery are 1.

Here's the updated code.

```
select LocationName
    ,BranchName
    ,AddLine1
    ,AddLine2
    ,Tel1
    ,case 
        when LocationType = 'CC'
            then 'Call Center'
        when LocationType = 'CL'
            then 'Operation'
        end as 'Location Type'
    ,case 
        when IsPurchase = 1 and IsHomeDelivery = 0
            then 'Purchase'
        when IsPurchase = 0 and IsHomeDelivery = 1
            then 'Home Delivery'
        when IsPurchase = 1 and IsHomeDelivery = 1
            then 'Purchase And Home Delevery'
        end as 'Type'
from PescaLocation
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around your answer.

Comment: Please check the answer icon to have this question answered.